# Реализация общего метода onClick для нескольких кнопок

Tags: java, javafx, button

Хочу реализовать общий метод обработки нажатия для группы кнопок с помощью switch. 
 Не получается эту идею запилить. С помощью if-else-if получилось

```js
    public void onClickTab1Buttons(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() == bt1) {
            lbl.setText("bt1");
        } else if (event.getSource() == bt2) {
            lbl.setText("bt2");
        } else if (event.getSource() == bt3) {
            lbl.setText("bt3");
        }
    }
```

Хочу примерно так:

```js
public void onClickTab1Buttons(ActionEvent event){

    switch (event.getSource()){
        case bt1:
            lbl.setText("bt1"); break;
        case bt2:
            lbl.setText("bt2"); break;
        case bt3:
            lbl.setText("bt3"); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Речь о реализации нажатий в приложении JavaFX часть кода *fxml ... <Button fx:id="bt1" onAction="#onClickTab1Buttons" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button1"> ... <Button fx:id="bt2" onAction="#onClickTab1Buttons" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button2"> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел.

```js
public void onClickTab1Buttons(ActionEvent event){

    Object obj = event.getSource();
    
    Button btn = (Button) obj;

    switch (btn.getId()){
        case "bt1":
            lbl.setText("bt1"); break;
        case "bt2":
            lbl.setText("bt2"); break;
        case "bt3":
            lbl.setText("bt3"); break;
    }
}
```

Так работает

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя использовать такие объекты в свиче. Из документации:
[The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)